# Order by count not sorting correctly - SQL (MS Access 2007)

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007

Overview:
Compare day to day trades for produce as agent for various accounts to find difference between agent and company holdings showing only what is new; codes in current trades, but not previous trades.

Objective:
Sort the trades by code (i.e. apples) with highest frequency.

Current table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        DATE | ACCT_CODE | TYPE | TYPE_DESCRIPTION |    CODE | DIFFERENCE | AGENT_HOLDING | COMPANY_HOLDING |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc107101 | prod |          produce |   apple |      -1500 |             0 |            1500 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc107101 | prod |          produce |   apple |       1500 |          2000 |             500 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc107101 | prod |          produce |   apple |          0 |             0 |               0 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc107101 | prod |          produce |   apple |          0 |         49797 |           49797 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc170000 | prod |          produce |  grapes |       2500 |          2500 |               0 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc170000 | prod |          produce |  grapes |      -1500 |             0 |            1500 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc008221 | caus |             cash |    cash |          0 |             0 |               0 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc008221 | caus |             cash | carrots |          0 |         43273 |           43274 |
| 01 Aug 2012 | acc008221 | caus |             cash |    cash |          0 |             0 |               0 |
| 01 Aug 2012 | acc008221 | caus |             cash | carrots |          0 |         43273 |           43274 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc179185 | prod |          produce |   mango |        125 |          2775 |            2650 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc179185 | prod |          produce |   mango |     -57646 |        453639 |          511286 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc636903 | prod |          produce |   mango |          0 |        481081 |          481081 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc001049 | prod |          produce |   mango |       2500 |          2500 |               0 |
| 02 Aug 2012 | acc001189 | prod |          produce |   apple |      -1091 |             0 |            1091 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code:

```
SELECT 
    Count(CurrentTrade.Code) AS CountOfCode, 
    CurrentTrade.date, 
    CurrentTrade.Acct_Code, 
    CurrentTrade.Type, 
    CurrentTrade.Code, 
    CurrentTrade.Agent_Holding, 
    CurrentTrade.Company_Holding, 
    CurrentTrade.Difference
FROM CurrentTrade 
LEFT JOIN PrevTrade 
    ON CurrentTrade.Company_Holding=PrevTrade.Company_Holding
WHERE (((PrevTrade.Company_Holding) Is Null) AND ((CurrentTrade.Code)<>'cash'))
GROUP BY 
    CurrentTrade.Code,CurrentTrade.date, 
    CurrentTrade.Acct_Code, 
    CurrentTrade.Type, 
    CurrentTrade.Agent_Holding, 
    CurrentTrade.Company_Holding, 
    CurrentTrade.Difference
ORDER BY count(CurrentTrade.Code) ASC;
```

Current results:

```
---------------------------------------------
| COUNTOFCODE |        DATE | TYPE |   CODE |
---------------------------------------------
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod | grapes |
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod | grapes |
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod |  apple |
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod |  apple |
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod |  apple |
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod |  apple |
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod |  apple |
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod |  mango |
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod |  mango |
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod |  mango |
|           1 | 02 Aug 2012 | prod |  mango |
---------------------------------------------
```

Issue:
How to fix to use correct ORDER BY frequency (apples, mango, grapes)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are doing the grouping too granular.

In this case it would probably make sense to exclude the three Amount columns (`AgentHolding`, `CompanyHolding` and `Difference`) from the `GROUP BY` clause and just aggregate them (`sum`) in the output.

Here's an example of what this change would produce: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc4d4/7

*Note: I left out the `left join` with the `PrevTrade` table as I did not know its structure and data, but hopefully this illustrates the intent.*

Comment: Awesome ..thanks!  This is much cleaner and works.  I added back the left join since the query compares 2 tables/2 dates on the fly.