# How to order by frequency without aggregating?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007

Overview: 
Compare day to day trades for produce as agent for various accounts to find difference between agent and company holdings showing only what is new; codes in current trades, but not previous trades.

Objective: 
Sort the trades by code (i.e. apples) with highest frequency.

Current Code:

```
SELECT 
    Count(CurrentTrade.Code) AS CountOfCode, 
    CurrentTrade.portfolio_code, 
    CurrentTrade.Type, 
    CurrentTrade.Code, 
    sum(CurrentTrade.Custodian_holding) AS AgentHolding, 
    sum(CurrentTrade.Company_holding) AS CompanyHolding, 
    sum(CurrentTrade.Difference) AS TotalDifference
FROM 
    CurrentTrade 
    LEFT JOIN PrevTrade 
    ON CurrentTrade.Company_holding = PrevTrade.Company_holding
WHERE 
    PrevTrade.Company_holding) Is Null
GROUP BY CurrentTrade.Code, CurrentTrade.portfolio_code, CurrentTrade.Code, CurrentTrade.Type
ORDER BY count(CurrentTrade.Code);
```

Current Results:

```
 CountOfCode        account_code        Type        Code        AgentHodling        CompanyHolding        TotalDifference
 1                  acc001049        prod        mango        2500                  0        2500
 1                  acc636903        prod        mango        481081.29        481081.285        0.01
 1                  acc179186        prod        mango        453639.61        511285.81        -57646.2
 1                  acc179185        prod        mango        2775               2650        125
 1                  acc170001        prod        grapes       0                     1500        -1500
 1                  acc170000        prod        grapes       2500        0        2500
 1                  acc107104        prod        apple        49797.22        49797.28        -0.06
 1                  acc107103        prod        apple        0        -0.06        0.06
 1                  acc107102        prod        apple        2000        500        1500
 1                  acc107101        prod        apple        0        1500        -1500
 1                  acc001189        prod        apple        0        1090.513        -1090.513
```

Reference:

I received an answer to this ([Order by count not sorting correctly - SQL (MS Access 2007)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888829/order-by-count-not-sorting-correctly-sql-ms-access-2007)) so this is a follow up.

Question:

Is it possible to order by frequency without aggregating all of the the results and still show order by highest frequency (apple, mango, grapes) including the account numbers associated?  
If use sum for the order by, “Cannot have aggregate function in ORDER BY” so I'm not sure I can do this and still keep the account numbers separate?

Answer (score 0):

Pull out the `ORDER BY` clause into an outer query and the inner query will calculate the frequency, as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    Count(CurrentTrade.Code) AS CountOfCode, 
    CurrentTrade.portfolio_code, 
    CurrentTrade.Type, 
    CurrentTrade.Code, 
    sum(CurrentTrade.Custodian_holding) AS AgentHolding, 
    sum(CurrentTrade.Company_holding) AS CompanyHolding, 
    sum(CurrentTrade.Difference) AS TotalDifference
FROM 
    CurrentTrade 
    LEFT JOIN PrevTrade 
    ON CurrentTrade.Company_holding = PrevTrade.Company_holding
WHERE 
    PrevTrade.Company_holding) Is Null
GROUP BY CurrentTrade.Code, CurrentTrade.portfolio_code, CurrentTrade.Code, CurrentTrade.Type
) ORDER BY CountOfCode ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!  I ended up creating two reports 1)without portfolio_code as summary with correct order by count and 2)with portfolio code for details.